# Reportlabs writing to multiple pages as shipping labels (full page) Python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am very new to using Reportlabs and am trying to find a better way to go about generating full page shipping labels that look like this:

[image]

so far I have this code (allbeit poorly written):

```
import datetime

from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

year = datetime.date.today().year

# IIRNumber = str(int(input("Month (digit): "))) + "-" + str(int(input("Shipment Number (include zero if before 10): ")))
# VMBENumber = "VBME-" + str(year)[-2:] + "-" + str(int(input("Enter VBME Number (last four digits: ")))
# PONUmber = input("Enter PO number or V for Various: ")
IIRNumber = "08-09"
VMBENumber = "VBME-21-1458"
PONUmber = "9185555"

ShipmentNumber = int(input("How many pieces in the shipment?: "))
print(VMBENumber)
print(IIRNumber)
print(ShipmentNumber)


def textobject_demo():

    my_canvas = canvas.Canvas("PDFGenerated.pdf",
                              pagesize=letter)
    # Create text_object
    text_object = my_canvas.beginText()
    # Set text location (x, y)


    # Write a line of text + carriage return
    # Set font face and size
    text_object.setFont('Times-Roman', 12)
    text_object.setTextOrigin(150, 730)

    for i in range(1, ShipmentNumber + 1):

        # Write text to the canvas
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text='To: Voisey Bay Mine Site – EXPANSION PROJECT (VBME)')
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="             C/O Innu Mikun Hangar")
        text_object.textLine(text="             Happy Valley-Goose Bay, NL")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="                     CC0012- " + VMBENumber + " - " + IIRNumber)
        text_object.textLine(text="                     Product Description:" + PONUmber)
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="                         Box " + str(i) + " of " + str(ShipmentNumber))
        text_object.textLine(text="                         Gross Weight: 14 lbs")
        text_object.textLine(text="                         Net Weight: 14 lbs")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="                         Dimensions: 9 L x 9 W x 9” H")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="             Special Storage Instruction: NO")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        text_object.textLine(text="             Attn:   IIR – REDPATH Canada Limited")
        text_object.textLine(text="                         Underground Garage ATTN: Mark / Shawn")
        text_object.textLine(text="")
        my_canvas.drawText(text_object)
        my_canvas.showPage()

    my_canvas.save()


if __name__ == '__main__'
    textobject_demo()
```

is there a better way?

I am trying to streamline the way we generate these froms with python as apposed to copy and pasting the info per page

Thanks for any and all help

littlejiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one is interested this is how I did it:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import pandas as pd
import datetime

po_numbers = []
l_in_in = []
w_in_in = []
h_in_in = []
alpha_letter = []
weights = []

data = pd.read_excel(r'/home/littlejiver/PycharmProjects/JSRFormGenerator/UOM conversions.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Order', 'L (in)', 'W (in)', 'H (in)', 'Weight (lbs)', 'Letter'])

alpha_or_num = input("Letters or Numbers (L or N)?: ")

for i in df["Order"].dropna():
    po_numbers.append(str(i).replace(".0", ""))
for i in df["L (in)"].dropna():
    l_in_in.append(i)
for i in df["W (in)"].dropna():
    w_in_in.append(i)
for i in df["H (in)"].dropna():
    h_in_in.append(i)
for i in df["Letter"].dropna():
    alpha_letter.append(i)
    print(i)
for i in df["Weight (lbs)"].dropna():
    weights.append(i)

number_of_pieces = len(df[df.Order.notnull()])

print(number_of_pieces)
iir_number = "IIR " + input("Enter IIR Number (XX-XX): ")
file_name = iir_number + " Shipping Labels.pdf"
document_title = iir_number + " Shipping Labels.pdf"
title = "To: Voisey's Bay Mine Site – EXPANSION PROJECT (VBME)"
ship_to_address_line_1 = "C/o Innu Mikun Hangar"
ship_to_address_line_2 = "Happy Valley-Goose Bay,"
year = datetime.date.today().year
vbme = input("Enter VMBE # (XXXX):")
vbme_number = "CC0012 - VBME-" + str(year)[-2:] + "-" + vbme + " " + iir_number
piece_number = " of " + str(number_of_pieces)
special_storage_instruction = "No"
attn_name_line_1 = "IIR – REDPATH Canada Limited"
attn_name_line_2 = "Underground Garage ATTN: Mark / Shawn"

pdf = canvas.Canvas(file_name)
pdf.setTitle(document_title)


def draw_my_ruler(pdf):
    pdf.drawString(100, 810, 'x100')
    pdf.drawString(200, 810, 'x200')
    pdf.drawString(300, 810, 'x300')
    pdf.drawString(400, 810, 'x400')
    pdf.drawString(500, 810, 'x500')
    pdf.drawString(600, 810, 'x600')
    pdf.drawString(700, 810, 'x700')
    pdf.drawString(800, 810, 'x800')

    pdf.drawString(10, 100, 'y100')
    pdf.drawString(10, 200, 'x200')
    pdf.drawString(10, 300, 'x300')
    pdf.drawString(10, 400, 'x400')
    pdf.drawString(10, 500, 'x500')
    pdf.drawString(10, 600, 'x600')
    pdf.drawString(10, 700, 'x700')
    pdf.drawString(10, 800, 'x800')


def create_label_page(piece, po_number, length, width, height, aletter, weight):
    pdf.setFont('Times-Bold', 17)
    pdf.drawCentredString(300, 720, title)

    pdf.setFont('Times-Bold', 14)
    pdf.drawString(150, 680, ship_to_address_line_1)
    pdf.drawString(150, 665, ship_to_address_line_2)
    pdf.drawString(150, 650, ship_to_address_line_3)

    pdf.setFont('Times-Roman', 13)
    pdf.drawString(175, 600, vbme_number)
    pdf.drawString(175, 575, "Product Description: " + po_number)
    if alpha_or_num == "L":
        pdf.drawString(175, 550, "Piece: " + str(piece) + " of " + str(number_of_pieces) + " (" + aletter + ")")
    else:
        pdf.drawString(175, 550, "Piece: " + str(piece) + " of " + str(number_of_pieces))
    pdf.drawString(175, 550, "Piece: " + str(piece) + " of " + str(number_of_pieces))
    pdf.drawString(175, 525, "L " + str(length) + " x W " + str(width) + " x H " + str(height) + '"')
    pdf.drawString(175, 500, "Gross Weight: " + str(weight) + " Lbs")
    pdf.drawString(175, 475, "Net Weight: " + str(weight) + " Lbs")
    pdf.drawString(150, 375, "Special Storage Instructions: " + special_storage_instruction)
    pdf.setFont('Times-Bold', 13)
    pdf.drawString(175, 300, "Attn: " + attn_name_line_1)
    pdf.drawString(210, 285, attn_name_line_2)

    pdf.showPage()


for num_po in range(1, len(po_numbers) + 1):
    print(str(num_po) + " of " + str(len(po_numbers)))

    create_label_page(num_po, po_numbers[num_po - 1], l_in_in[num_po - 1], w_in_in[num_po - 1], h_in_in[num_po - 1],
                      alpha_letter[num_po - 1], weights[num_po - 1])

pdf.save()
```